How is the pseudometric on a quasinormed TVS defined?
In this Wikipedia page, it is claimed that "every quasinormed topological vector space is pseudometrisable".
How is the pseudometric defined for such spaces? Is there an explicit description?

There is a construction in the proof of Theorem 1.24 in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

@Jochen I found this link, and Theorem 1.24 seems to refer to metrics for TVSs with countable local bases, which would seem to include quasinormed TVSs. Thus, to double-check, quasinormed TVSs are not only pseudometrisable, but fully metrisable?

Some authors always require TVS to be Hausdorff (like, e.g., Rudin) but others do not. According to the Wikipedia page, quasinormed spaces are Hausdorff and hence they are indeed metrisable (and not only pseudometrisable).

@Jochen Thanks so much. If you’d like to write a short answer summarising what you’ve said, I’ll accept it.

I hope you don't mind that I typed up an answer to this question since this question had been left unanswered for a while. Of course, feel free to accept Jochen's answer if one is also typed up.

@DeanMiller No problem. I was going to do so myself, but I became preoccupied.

As stated in the Wikipedia page, if $p$ is a quasinorm on the vector space $X$ then $p$ induces a translation-invariant topology on $X$ with a neighbourhood base at the origin given by sets of the form
\begin{equation}
\{x\in X : p(x) < 1/n \}
\end{equation}
as $n$ ranges over $\mathbb{N}$. It does not take too much work to use the definition of the quasinorm $p$ to show that this topology induces a Hausdorff topological vector space structure on $X$. Furthermore, since this topology has a countable neighbourhood base at the origin, this vector topology on $X$ can be induced by a translation-invariant metric. For a proof of the last statement, two places to look are Theorem 1.24 in "Functional Analysis" by Rudin and Theorem 2.3.11 in "An Introduction to Banach Space Theory" by Megginson. Both proofs contain a construction of such a metric which makes explicit use of a given countable neighbourhood base. It is also worth mentioning that the construction of the metric has similarities to the standard proof of Urysohn's lemma.
